# Iptables: redundant Output ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED rule before individual port rules

Tags: iptables

My `Iptables` to connect to VPS using static ip `X.X.X.X`
and to allow VPS to update and install packages

```
*filter

#Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and reject traffic
#to localhost that does not originate from lo0.
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

#Allow traffic from address X.X.X.X
-A INPUT -i eth0 -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#Allow DNS
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow HTTP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Allow HTTPS
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Reject everything else
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j DROP

COMMIT
```

Question: why is the rule

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

unnecessary?

The other 3 output rules,

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

are for `--ctstate ESTABLISHED` and only for ports `53,80,443`

Is there a difference adding `RELATED` to the `ctstate`?

If the updates are only from `mirrors.linode.com`, can I further improve the rules using `-s mirrors.linode.com`? What if the `hostname` `ip` change many months later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do not need this rules**:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

They must be replaced with single one:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Explanation: this rule are needed to receive traffic from connections which *your host are initiated*. This rule will do not applying for connection which initiated by *remote hosts*.

**Iptables rules are applying to packets in certain order which you define**.

If packets are comming to host they placed in INPUT chain and iptables apply INPUT rules. 
Let's convert your rules by chains:

```
*filter

-A INPUT -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -j DROP

COMMIT
```

I was delete all comments to reduce the answer.

---

Answer for your questions.

**This rule**:

```
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

permit all traffic from local system to remote host when connection are initiated by remote host. In other words: this rule allows your host to answer for remote connections. This rule are needed for normal work.

**RELATED are needed for new connections which initiated inside other permitted session**. (e.g. passive ftp connections with dynamic ports range).

**The bad idea to type DNS name in iptables rules** - name resolving occure one times when iptables rules are load. And other reasons...

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand what u mean for the ``-A INPUT -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT``, but is ``it -A INPUT -i `` instead, because -o is for output?

Comment: The separation of input and output as chains is good idea, i will follow this convention

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo. I fixed `-o` to `-i`. Thx